# ADF 11.1.1.4, Weblogic 10.3.4 and Internet Explorer 10

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10, oracle-adf, weblogic-10.x

When viewing our application in IE 10 there multiple errors such as tables constantly fetching data and never displaying it, and additional various errors such as the page format not being correct.

I have referred to the Oracle website and know that IE10 is not certified for use until 11.1.1.7, but is there anything that we can do to improve our IE10 compatibility without upgrading?

Answer (score 0):

There is a small hack you can do to make the ADF think it's not IE10 and it's IE9 so it can display the data by manipulating the user-agent

You can find it explained in [this article](http://jonasdegraaff.blogspot.nl/2013/11/how-to-run-your-adf-111x-application.html) while it talks about IE11 you can still apply the same approach to your problem.